Zero-divisors in a unital $C^*$-algebra
I have been studying the functional calculus for unital $C^*$-algebras. This says the following.
Let $A$ be an unital $C^*$-algebra and $a \in A$ a normal element. We denote by $B:= C^*(1, a) \subset A$ the unital abelian $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$ generated by $1$ and $a$. Then, from the Gelfand representation we get a $*$-isomorphism $\varphi: C(\sigma(a)) \to B$, where $\varphi(z) = a$ and $z: \sigma(a) \to \mathbf{C}$ is the inclusion ($\sigma(a)$ is the spectrum of $a$ in $\mathbf{C}$).
We can see from this if $\sigma(a)$ is a finite set, then the polynomial $p(z) := \prod_{\lambda \in \sigma(a)} (z - \lambda)$ is equal to $0 \in C(\sigma(a))$. Hence, with the isomorphism $\varphi$ we can see that $A$ has in fact zero-divisors. This motivates my question.

Question: Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra in which the cardinality of the spectrum of every normal element (except for scalars) in $A$ is infinite. Is then true that $A$ has no (non-zero) zero-divisors?

In other words, the question is whether the following equivalence holds. Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. Then, is it true that $A$ has a non-zero zero-divisor if and only if it has a normal element (not equal to scalar) with finite spectrum?
I would somehow like to generalize to the approach for the question as in the previous direction, i.e. I want to find a continuous function on $\sigma(a)$ which would have to 'factor'. Any suggestions are welcome.

Doesn't every unital $C^*$ algebra have a normal element with finite spectrum (the unit)?

@KeeperOfSecrets You are right, I should have left out scalars.

Consider $C[0,1].$ It admits zero divisors.

All scalar multiples of $1$ also has a singleton as its spectrum. Consider the commutative unital $C^*$-algebra $A=C([0, 1])$. All elements of $A$ are obvioiusly normal. And for any $f\in A$, if $f$ is not a constant, its range/spectrum must be infinite since as the continuous image of $[0, 1]$, it has to be connected so cannot be discrete.
However, $A$ clearly has many zero divisors. Just take any continuous function $f$ that vanishes on $[0, 1/2]$, but not on $[1/2, 1$] (e.g. $f(x) = x-1/2$ when $x\in [1/2, 1]$), and $g$ that vanishes on $[1/2, 1]$, but not on $[0, 1/2]$ (e.g. $g(x)=x-1/2$ when $x\in [0, 1/2]$), then $fg\equiv 0$.
With the same idea (by continuous functional calculus and Tietze extension theorem), you can prove any unital $C^*$-algebra has zero divisors, except $\mathbb C$.
